# Fast Fourier Transform in processing of an input signal from Arduino

Tags: java, c++, arduino, processing

I have been trying to get audio signal from an arduino microphone. First I setup my arduino in Free Running Mode, and then I wait for a message from Processing that is a capital A. When Processing sends the serial signal, my arduino should send back 16 audio amplitude samples. Then, processing should take those 16 audio samples and pass them by the Fast Fourier Transform in orden to get a real time frequency spectrum. However, it seems that my Arduino never detects the capital A, and also, if I try to send the samples from my Arduino without waiting for the capital A, when Processing gets the samples it seems something went wrong with the serial communication. I tried with many arduinos and different serial cables to be sure it was no the problem. Here you are the arduino code:

```
// Arrays to save our results in

int values[16];


// Define various ADC prescaler
const unsigned char PS_16 = (1 << ADPS2);
const unsigned char PS_32 = (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS0);
const unsigned char PS_64 = (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1);
const unsigned char PS_128 = (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0);

// Setup the serial port and pin 2
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);

  // set up the ADC
  ADCSRA &= ~PS_128;  // remove bits set by Arduino library

  // you can choose a prescaler from above.
  // PS_16, PS_32, PS_64 or PS_128
  ADCSRA |= PS_64;    // set our own prescaler to 64 

}


void loop() {  
  unsigned int i;

  for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
      values[i] = analogRead(2);

  }

  if(Serial.available() > 0) {

    char c = Serial.read();
    if(c == 'A') { 
      for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
        Serial.println(values[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

Here you are the processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
FFT fft;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class

void setup() 
{

  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 115200);
  size(800, 600);
  background(255);
  fft = new FFT(16, 16000);


}


String mensaje;

float[] magnitudes = new float[16];
int contador = 0;
byte request = true;
void draw()
{

  if(request) {
     myPort.write('A');//Solicita nuevos datos.
     request = false;
  } 
  while(!request) { 
    if(myPort.available()>0) {
       mensaje = myPort.readStringUntil(13);
       print(" mensaje: "+mensaje);
       if(mensaje != null){
         magnitudes[contador++] = int(mensaje);
       }
    }
    if(contador >= 15) {
      contador=0;
      fft.forward(magnitudes);
      request = true; 
      fill(100);
      rect(0,0,800,800);
      for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) { 
         fill(200);
         rect(i*30+10, 0, 10, fft.getBand(i) * 0.1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you a lot for your attention!

Comment: so why is C++ tagged?

Comment: A 16-point FFT? That gets you 8 frequency bins. Even if your sample rate is as low as 8 Khz (Nyquist frequency 4 kHz), each bin would still be 500 Hz wide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer CoryKramer. C++ is tagged because (as far as I know) the Arduino IDE is based on C++ code, so I thought that it would be possible that my problem could be related to the C++ syntax (for example).

Comment: I agree MSalters, That would be a large wide for each bin. However, I began trying just a little of samples (only 16) because I though this would make the program faster. The plan is to increase the amount of bins after I can run the code and see how fast it is. I tried using the spectrum.py program given in adafruit, which is intended to run with a teensyduino, and the ¨refresh¨ was a little slow.